# GUI inside LXC 2.0/LXD containers

Tags: pulseaudio, intel-graphics, lxc, lxd

The aim is to containerize a few GUI apps (Kodi and Retroplayer being the main ones) and launch them from the host. Due to the nature of the apps, I'd need audio support and gpu acceleration, with no lag or additional latency.

I was hoping to containerize the whole desktop environment, and keep the host bare without a desktop environment, but not sure if that's possible.

Can anyone point me in the direction of documentation on how to setup an LXC 2.0 container with audio and intel gpu acceleration.

I know it's possible to at least containerize the gui apps and launch them within the hosts desktop environment, as I've seen examples where people have achieved this. But can only find documentation for LXC 1.0, which of course does not work for 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm yet unsure how to completely containerize a display-manager in a headless server.

For running gui apps with audio in containers, this [tutorial](https://blog.simos.info/how-to-easily-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/) worked for me. The following is a summary of steps. Note that I'm using LXD 3.5 (snap) on an Ubuntu 18.04.1.

**1.  Save the following into a text file named `lxdguiprofile.txt`**:

```
config:
  environment.DISPLAY: :0
  raw.idmap: both 1000 1000
  user.user-data: |
    #cloud-config
    runcmd:
      - 'sed -i "s/; enable-shm = yes/enable-shm = no/g" /etc/pulse/client.conf'
      - 'echo export PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/.pulse-native | tee --append /home/ubuntu/.profile'
    packages:
      - x11-apps
      - mesa-utils
      - pulseaudio
description: GUI LXD profile
devices:
  PASocket:
    path: /tmp/.pulse-native
    source: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
    type: disk
  X0:
    path: /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
    source: /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
    type: disk
  mygpu:
    type: gpu
name: gui
used_by:
```

**2. Add the profile to your LXD instance:**

```
lxc profile create gui
cat lxdguiprofile.txt | lxc profile edit gui
```

**3. Apply the profile to a container:**

```
lxc profile add "$container" gui
lxc restart "$container"
```

That should be it! To test your gui, execute the following commands:

```
# Login to the ubuntu user in the container.
lxc exec "$container" -- su ubuntu -l 

# This should show an animation of gears if all is well.
glxgears

# This command shows the audio setup info.
pactl info
```

Note that, in my setup, the gui only works in the default `ubuntu` user inside the container. I'm unsure why, but the steps can probably be tweaked to allow other container users to access the gui. I have also ran into trouble running hardware accelerated apps, such as WineHQ or Steam.